# storage.sync.get() returning undefined only on FIrefox

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension, firefox-addon

When I call the getter, it returns undefined on Firefox, it should return an empty object. It returns undefined only on Firefox, on Chrome it works perfectly fine and returns an empty object.

```
chrome.storage.sync.get(res => {
  console.log(res);
});

// Firefox: undefined
// Chrome: {}
```

My web extension is supposed to work on both Chrome and Firefox.

Also, my web extension does set storage.sync before this, I just don't think I need to add that to my example since Firefox returns undefined no matter what and chrome returns what it should.

Comment: so, regardless if you `set` an `empty object` or actual data, Firefox "returns" undefined (by "return" you mean the `console.log(res)` is undefined since there's no `return` in your code

Comment: Yes, that's exactly what I meant @JaromandaX

Comment: Perhaps you are not setting it correctly (there are differences between chrum-extension and firefox-addon)

Comment: I think that's not true since storage.local works exactly the same on Firefox and Chrome, I know this because I am switching from local to sync. Chrome survived the transfer with no errors, Firefox didn't @JaromandaX

Comment: well ... something must be different, wouldn't you agree

Comment: Oh, ... have you read the documentation for storage.sync.get ... chrome and firefox do things differently - https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/Add-ons/WebExtensions/API/storage/StorageArea/get#examples - not sure why local would work and sync not work, since ... as I said, you're doing it wrong

Comment: @JaromandaX Telling me I am doing it wrong doesn't help me one bit. I know the problem is on my side but I am asking for help. I have read the documentation but I don't know what I am doing wrong.

Comment: the examples I linked to - https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/Add-ons/WebExtensions/API/storage/StorageArea/get#examples - are self explanatory

Answer (score 2):

The examples at MDN of how to use `browser.storage` (the equivalent of `chrome.storage`) - https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/Add-ons/WebExtensions/API/storage/StorageArea/get#examples - so I won't repeat them here

As you can see, Firefox storageArea get returns a Promise and does not take a callback argument - so your code would need to be very different in Firefox compared to Chrome

Now, to make coding simpler between Chrome and Firefox extensions, you'd want a function that works identically regardless

So

```
async function storageLocalGet(keys, callback) {
    if (inChrome) {
        return chrome.storage.local.get(keys, callback);
    }
    const result = await browser.storage.local.get(keys);
    callback(result);        
}
// usage
 
storgeLocalGet(res => {
  console.log(res);
});
```

All that is left for YOU to do is determine if you're `inChrome` or not, and the rest takes care of itself

Alternatively, to use the Firefox pattern

```
function storageLocalGet(keys) {
    if (inFirefox) {
        return browser.storage.local.get(keys);
    }
    return new Promise(resolve => chrome.storage.local.get(keys, resolve));
}
// usage
const res = await storageLocalGet();
console.log(res);
```

Again, you'll need to determine which browser you're in - but also, your code that uses the storage.get will need to change to work with Promises